# Can $T = R \times F$ be used in rolling with slipping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque

There is a solid cylinder rolling with slipping down an inclined plane.

I am trying to find $\alpha$ (i.e. the angular acceleration) using the relation $\tau = I \alpha$. I know the value of $R$, $F_{net}$, $I$.

Can I use the relation $T = R \times F$ even though there is slipping because I know that if there is slipping, we can't use the relation $v = r.\omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Torque is a definition that is independent of the system or what it is doing. As long as you have a force, and you define a "reference point", then you can find the torque of that force about that reference point.

Just keep in mind that the net torque is not the torque of the net force. i.e. $\boldsymbol\tau_\text{net}\neq\mathbf r\times\mathbf F_\text{net}$ in general.

Comment: Could you please explain the last line clearly...

Comment: For R x F, will we use $F_{friction}$ and not $F_{net}$ right? Because friction is providing the torque. This could also explain your last statement that since all the forces may not contribute towards torque, we cannot use $F_{net}$...

Comment: @HSB Saying that the net torque is not the torque of the net force does not mean not all forces contribute to the net torque. It's just that $\tau_\text{net}\neq r\times\sum F$. As an easy counter example, consider turning a wheel with your two hands on opposite sides of the wheel. The wheel turns (net torque $\neq0$) but the center of mass does not move  (net force $=0$). Each force still contributes to the net torque though.